# How to use Lambda expressions with custom class objects

Tags: c++

Trying to use a Lambda expression in STL::find to locate a particular object in a vector

I have written my code based on several examples and have tried many different variations of the Lambda, captures, etc. I have overloaded the '==' operator for my class (not sure if I need to in this case, since I'm not actually comparing object to object, but object.property to object.property)

```
//MAIN.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include "Employee.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::vector<Employee> staff
    {
        { "Kate", "Gregory", 1000 },
        { "Obvious", "Artificial", 2000 },
        { "Fake", "Name", 1000 },
        { "Alan", "Turing", 2000 },
        { "Grace", "Hopper", 2000 },
        { "Anita", "Borg", 2000 }
    };

    auto v3 = staff;
    sort(begin(v3), end(v3));

    string searchName = "Hopper";
    auto result = find(begin(staff), end(staff), [searchName](Employee e)->bool {return e.firstname == searchName; });

    return 0;
}


//EMPLOYEE CLASS (in Employee.h)
#pragma once
#include <string>

class Employee
{
public:
    Employee(std::string first, std::string last, int sal) :
        firstname(first), lastname(last), salary(sal) {}

    int getSalary() { return salary; }
    std::string getSortingName() { return lastname + ", " + firstname; }

    std::string firstname;
    std::string lastname;
    int salary;

    bool operator < (const Employee& other)
    {
        if (lastname < other.lastname)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    bool operator == (Employee other)
    {
        if (lastname == other.lastname &&
            firstname == other.firstname &&
            salary == other.salary)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
};
```

When compiling, I get the following error code:

Error   C2678   binary '==': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'Employee' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\include\xutility    3520

It almost seems like no matter what I do, I get this same error. The only way I have been able to defeat it is to comment out the failing line...that starts with "auto result = find..."

Comment: ot: `if (condition) return true; else return false;` is the same as `return condition;`

Comment: Voting to close as a typo.  `find_if` takes a comparator.  `find` takes a value of the range element type.  `auto result = find(begin(staff), end(staff), [searchName](Employee e)->bool {return e.firstname == searchName; });` -> `auto result = find_if(begin(staff), end(staff), [searchName](Employee e)->bool {return e.firstname == searchName; });`

Comment: That lambda might as well take a `const Employee&` (or `const auto&`). There's no need to create a copy of each element in the container.

Answer (score 9):

I think you are using the wrong function. According to [this](https://it.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find), `find` has as a third parameter a constant value, while `find_if` has a `UnaryPredicate`, which is what you are trying to achieve.

Change with `find_if` and it will compile.